# in flutter, ToggleButton doesn't refresh after tap, but onPress fuction works

Tags: android, flutter, dart

## The Problem

In my stateful widget, I add a toggle button to a new page, to modify the state of another value.
Here is my page:

```
  Widget prefixEditor() {
    String value = widget.num.prefix;
    var editCon = TextEditingController(text: value);
    bool editable = type == "custom";
    var prefixEditField = TextField(
      enabled: editable,
      onSubmitted: (newValue) {
        widget.num.customPrefix = newValue;
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      controller: editCon,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(title: const Text('Please select the form of prefix')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            ToggleButtons(
              isSelected: prefixTag,
              onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < prefixTag.length; idx++) {
                      prefixTag[idx] = idx == index;
                    }
                  });
                  switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                      type = "default";
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      type = "sound devices";
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      type = "custom";
                      break;
                  }
                  widget.num.recorderType = type;
                  editCon.text = widget.num.prefix;
                  editable = type == "custom";
                  // prefixEditField.enabled = editable;
                  setState(() {});
              },
              children: const [
                Text("Date"),
                Text("Sound Devices"),
                Text("Custom")
              ]),
              prefixEditField,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

in this page, `prefixTag` is actually initiallized in the `init` fuction of the stateful widget. Just like the title, the `isSelected` visually doesn't change after tap, but actually the `onPressed` works, all the values including `prefixTag` changed as expect.

## The context

the page is called by a `onLongPress` of `GestureDetector`:

```
          onLongPress: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context, 
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => prefixEditor())
              );
          },
```

And the `GestureDetector` is a part of Stateful Widget called `FileNameDisplayCard` which is in a streambuilder:

```
return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: num.value,
      initialData: _initCounter,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Center(
          child: FileNameDisplayCard(
              num: num, snapshot: snapshot, style: textStyle),
        );
      },
    );
```

## What I tried ...

I just tried to copy a piece of code that works in another page:

```
          ToggleButtons(
            isSelected: [
              editedType == '特写',
              editedType == '近景',
              editedType == '中景',
              editedType == '全景',
              editedType == '远景',
            ],
            onPressed: (index) {
              setState(() {
                switch (index) {
                  case 0:
                    editedType = '特写';
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    editedType = '近景';
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    editedType = '中景';
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    editedType = '全景';
                    break;
                  case 4:
                    editedType = '远景';
                    break;
                }
              });
            },
            children: const [
              Text('特写'),
              Text('近景'),
              Text('中景'),
              Text('全景'),
              Text('远景'),
            ],
          ),
```

the same problem happens.